# MGCB Content Builder Won't Launch Properly

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, monogame

I'm trying to use the Monogame Content Builder in Linux with VS Code. I installed [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgcb-vscode.mgcb-vscode&ssr=false#qna) in order to easily run the `Content.mgcb` file, but when I right click the file, the option to run it doesn't appear. Alternatively, when I run `dotnet mgcb-editor` in the terminal, this window shows up, but there's no option to import a file or do anything! This is what it looks like: [image]

What am I doing wrong? Why won't the extension work, and why won't the the editor open properly? I'm pretty sure the editor should look like this (this image is from a tutorial). [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Linux GTK version displays differently than the windows version.

Use the New button(Leftmost on Bar) or Open button to specify the `.mgcb` file in the project folder.

Once a file is open, the Bar adds buttons on the left for Build, Rebuild and Clean and Save on the right.

Right-Click the Content node under project to Add existing or add new or build.